# Didn't find class on path: DexPathList for KeyGenParameterSpec$Builder

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, key-pair

I am using KeyGenParameterSpec to define my key specification. When I run the application I get the below error in logs:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec$Builder" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.rsa.mobile.transactionsigningsdk-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64,
>   /system/lib64]]

Below is my MainActivity.java:

```
 package com.rsa.mobile.transactionsigningsdk;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.rsa.mobile.transactionsigningsdk.enrollment.DeviceEnrollmentHelper;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Log.i("Testing message", "App started");
    DeviceEnrollmentHelper deh =new DeviceEnrollmentHelper();
    deh.enroll();
    Log.i("Testing message", "Job Done");


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Below is the code being called from the MainActivity.java:

```
 public DeviceEnrollmentResponse enroll() {

    if(isEnrolled()) {
        return new DeviceEnrollmentResponse(null,StatusReasonCode.DEVICE_ALREADY_ENROLLED);
    }
    else{
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
                    "RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");

            /*KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(android.content.Context this)
                    .setAlias("trsdk")
                    .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=Sample Name, O=Android Authority"))
                    .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                    .setKeySize(KEY_SIZE)
                    .build();*/
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(
                    new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                            "trsdk",
                            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
                            .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"))
                            .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256,
                                    KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA384,
                                    KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                            .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                            .build());
            KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
            //Get the public key from the KeyPair
            PublicKey pk=keyPair.getPublic();
            //remove
            Log.i("Testing Message","Inside Enroll()");
            Log.i("Testing Message", String.valueOf(pk));

            //To Ask
            if (pk==null){
                return new DeviceEnrollmentResponse(null, StatusReasonCode.UNKNOWN_ERR);
            }
            else{
                return new DeviceEnrollmentResponse(pk, StatusReasonCode.DEVICE_SUCCESSFULLY_ENROLLED);
            }

            } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    //To Ask
    return null;
}
```

Below is my AndroidMaifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Below is the app build.gradle:

> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>
> android {
>       compileSdkVersion 23
>       buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
>
> ```
> defaultConfig {
>     applicationId "com.rsa.mobile.transactionsigningsdk"
>     minSdkVersion 14
>     targetSdkVersion 23
>     versionCode 1
>     versionName "1.0"
> }
> buildTypes {
>     release {
>         minifyEnabled false
>         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>     }
> } }
> ```
>
> dependencies {
>
> ```
> compile ('com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.7'){
>         exclude group: 'xmlpull'
> }
> compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
> testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
> compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0' }
> ```

Below is the stacktrace of the errors:

> 11-24 11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process:
>   com.rsa.mobile.transactionsigningsdk, PID: 27882 11-24 11:07:52.485
>   27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed
>   resolution of: Landroid/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec$Builder;
>   11-24 11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.rsa.mobile.transactionsigningsdk.enrollment.DeviceEnrollmentHelper.enroll(DeviceEnrollmentHelper.java:82)
>   11-24 11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.rsa.mobile.transactionsigningsdk.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
>   11-24 11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6088) 11-24
>   11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>   11-24 11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
>   11-24 11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>   11-24 11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 11-24
>   11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1322)
>   11-24 11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 11-24
>   11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 11-24 11:07:52.485
>   27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290) 11-24
>   11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 11-24 11:07:52.485
>   27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 11-24 11:07:52.485
>   27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>   11-24 11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699) 11-24
>   11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec$Builder" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.rsa.mobile.transactionsigningsdk-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64,
>   /system/lib64]] 11-24 11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   11-24 11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511) 11-24
>   11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469) 11-24
>   11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.rsa.mobile.transactionsigningsdk.enrollment.DeviceEnrollmentHelper.enroll(DeviceEnrollmentHelper.java:82) 
>   11-24 11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.rsa.mobile.transactionsigningsdk.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27) 
>   11-24 11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6088)  11-24
>   11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
>   11-24 11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307) 
>   11-24 11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416) 
>   11-24 11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)  11-24
>   11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1322) 
>   11-24 11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  11-24
>   11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)  11-24 11:07:52.485
>   27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)  11-24
>   11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  11-24 11:07:52.485
>   27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  11-24 11:07:52.485
>   27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
>   11-24 11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)  11-24
>   11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Suppressed:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec$Builder 11-24
>   11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 11-24 11:07:52.485
>   27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781) 11-24
>   11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841) 11-24
>   11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504) 11-24
>   11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:          ... 16 more 11-24
>   11:07:52.485 27882-27882/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class
>   loader; no stack available 11-24 11:07:52.485 32736-32736/?
>   D/AsyncTaskServiceImpl: Submit a task: k 11-24 11:07:52.487
>   27882-27882/? D/AppTracker: App Event: crash 11-24 11:07:52.487
>   1092-22412/? W/ActivityManager: getRunningAppProcesses: caller 10156
>   does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output 11-24 11:07:52.489
>   1092-10061/? W/ActivityManager: getRunningAppProcesses: caller 10156
>   does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output 11-24 11:07:52.490
>   32736-27837/? D/k: Processing package:
>   com.rsa.mobile.transactionsigningsdk 11-24 11:07:52.490 32736-32736/?
>   D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Loading module com.google.android.gms.vision from APK
>   com.google.android.gms 11-24 11:07:52.492 1092-4065/? D/WifiService:
>   Client connection lost with reason: 4 11-24 11:07:52.503 1092-4736/?
>   W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 1
>   com.rsa.mobile.transactionsigningsdk/.MainActivity 11-24 11:07:52.505
>   13111-13111/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid parameter
>   app 11-24 11:07:52.505 13111-13111/?
>   E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid package name : Perhaps
>   you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras? 11-24 11:07:52.520
>   1092-27935/? D/DropBoxManagerService: file ::
>   /data/system/dropbox/data_app_crash@1448343472518.txt 11-24
>   11:07:52.535 1092-1169/? W/ActivityManager:  Dismiss app error dialog
>   : com.rsa.mobile.transactionsigningsdk 11-24 11:07:52.537
>   27882-27882/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27882 SIG: 9 11-24
>   11:07:52.549 32736-27837/? D/GassUtils: Found app info for package
>   com.rsa.mobile.transactionsigningsdk:1. Hash:
>   b6b6c7a4a5de3ea7df9c51284188b1040033e02a491ec95fee9371f7817bc00c 11-24
>   11:07:52.549 32736-27837/? D/k: Found info for package
>   com.rsa.mobile.transactionsigningsdk in db. 11-24 11:07:52.562
>   1092-10061/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 27936:com.yatra.base/u0a143
>   for broadcast com.yatra.base/com.moe.pushlibrary.AppUpdateReceiver
>   11-24 11:07:52.562 367-367/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing
>   /proc/27882/oom_score_adj; errno=22 11-24 11:07:52.581 1092-22411/?
>   I/ActivityManager: Process com.rsa.mobile.transactionsigningsdk (pid
>   27882) has died 11-24 11:07:52.582 1092-1163/? V/ActivityManager:
>   killProcessGroupAsync took 0 ms for PID 27882 on thread 16 11-24
>   11:07:52.587 27936-27936/? W/ResourcesManager: Asset path
>   '/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar' does not exist or
>   contains no resources. 11-24 11:07:52.601 27936-27936/? I/MultiDex: VM
>   with version 2.1.0 has multidex support 11-24 11:07:52.601
>   27936-27936/? I/MultiDex: install 11-24 11:07:52.601 27936-27936/?
>   I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is
>   disabled. 11-24 11:07:52.601 27936-27936/? I/MultiDex: install 11-24
>   11:07:52.601 27936-27936/? I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support,
>   MultiDex support library is disabled. 11-24 11:07:52.614 27936-27936/?
>   D/MoEngage_v510: MoEController:Context is null cannot bind service
>   now. 11-24 11:07:52.616 1092-1181/? W/WindowManager: Failed looking up
>   window 11-24 11:07:52.616 1092-1181/? W/WindowManager:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@35e88e7 does not exist 11-24 11:07:52.616
>   1092-1181/? W/WindowManager:     at
>   com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8708)
>   11-24 11:07:52.616 1092-1181/? W/WindowManager:     at
>   com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8699)
>   11-24 11:07:52.616 1092-1181/? W/WindowManager:     at
>   com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow(WindowManagerService.java:2620)
>   11-24 11:07:52.616 1092-1181/? W/WindowManager:     at
>   com.android.server.wm.Session.remove(Session.java:187) 11-24
>   11:07:52.616 1092-1181/? W/WindowManager:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:3015)
>   11-24 11:07:52.616 1092-1181/? W/WindowManager:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:5502) 11-24
>   11:07:52.616 1092-1181/? W/WindowManager:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3321)
>   11-24 11:07:52.616 1092-1181/? W/WindowManager:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 11-24
>   11:07:52.616 1092-1181/? W/WindowManager:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 11-24 11:07:52.616 1092-1181/?
>   W/WindowManager:     at
>   android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 11-24 11:07:52.616
>   1092-1181/? W/WindowManager:     at
>   com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46) 11-24
>   11:07:52.618 27936-27936/? I/MoEngage_v510: MoEUtils: SDK initialized.
>   MoEngage SDK version: 510 11-24 11:07:52.618 1092-22411/?
>   W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus
>   gain of:
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@34f79c48
>   attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@132d42ec

Can anyone help out please: I have tried out cleaning the project, re-importing it as suggested in related questions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am also facing similar issue for my system-app update.After updating it still point to system partition.did you find solution?any kind of help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

this is because you are using some device that isn't using API's 23 (Android 6.0 or above)